# 'emacs': unknown terminal type

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm getting the following message in the PyCharm Console when selecting the debug button:

```
pydev debugger: process 13699 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 145.1504)
'emacs': unknown terminal type.
```

I'm running on Ubuntu and echo $TERM displays: xterm

Comment: When you say $TERM=xterm, is `xterm` the output of `echo $TERM`, or have you set `$TERM=xterm`? If it's the latter, it should be `TERM=xterm`. Also, what is the output of `echo $TERMINAL`?

Comment: echo $TERMINAL displays nothing, echo $TERM displays xterm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed emacs, elpy and ipython and the next time I ran pyCharm I ended up with this issue as well.

I fixed it by editing:
`/home/$user/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_ipython_console.py` (line 6 for me)

Before, giving error:

```
os.environ['TERM'] = 'emacs' #to use proper page_more() for paging
```

After, and no more error:

```
os.environ['TERM'] = 'xterm' #to use proper page_more() for paging
```

Hope this helps :)